# React Formik: IsSubmitting not working for me

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, formik, onsubmit

I am using Formik in my react application. I tried to change the state of button enbales/disabled using isSubmitting property but its not seems working. Neither button text updating nor styling. I have found a example solution but that's not working either. Here is the link of example code that isn't working. Can anyone explain please?
[Formik sandbox code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-issubmitting-working-nxfsd?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do anything special - formik automatically awaits the `onSubmit` handler. Just make sure it's returning a `Promise` that can be awaited.

In your example you are returning immediately from `handleSubmit`.

```
 async function handleSubmit(values, { setSubmitting }) {
    console.log("submitted");

    setTimeout(() => setSubmitting(false), 2000);
    // this returns immediately
  }
```

Update your example code like this:

```
  const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

  async function handleSubmit(values) {
    console.log("submitted",  values);
    await delay(2000)
  }
```

[image: Edit formik-issubmitting-working (forked)]